# Is there any reference mapping a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

type error : mapping function

mapping function is not working any suggestions ?

```
Error:
TypeError : messages.map is not function
```

I was seeing more errors when try to write a map function in react
trying different methods but it was not working
Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
<div className="chat__body">
                {messages.map((message)=> (
                    <p className={`chat__message ${message.received && "chat__receiver"}`}>
                        <span className= "chat__name">{message.name}</span>
                        {message.message}
                        <span className="class__timestamp">{message.timeStamp}</span>
                    </p>
                ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the data / initialization of messages

Comment: `map` is used for the type of `array`. The error message shows `messages` is not the type of `array`.